# Python: Issue with inserting large dataframe (1.2M rows) into Postgres

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using the Pandas insert method (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-sql-method) to take CSVs that have been converted from .mdb files and insert them into Postgres. One of the tables that I am trying to convert is 1.2 million rows and is exceeding the CPU power of my EC2 instance. Is there a way to modify or break up this function in order to handle a CSV of this size? Other tables that are 150K-300K rows are working just fine. Thanks.

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def psql_insert_copy(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    # gets a DBAPI connection that can provide a cursor
    dbapi_conn = conn.connection
    with dbapi_conn.cursor() as cur:
        s_buf = StringIO()
        writer = csv.writer(s_buf)
        writer.writerows(data_iter)
        s_buf.seek(0)

        columns = ', '.join('"{}"'.format(k) for k in keys)
        if table.schema:
            table_name = '{}.{}'.format(table.schema, table.name)
        else:
            table_name = table.name

        sql = 'COPY {} ({}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV'.format(
            table_name, columns)
        cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=s_buf)

def df_to_postgres(table_name, dataframe):

    df = dataframe

    engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{PGusername}:{PGpassword}@{PGendpoint}:5432/testDB')

    df.to_sql(table_name.lower(), engine, if_exists='replace', method=psql_insert_copy)
```

EDIT: I added a chucksize argument into the df.to_sql statement and am still getting a memory error. Error notes are below.

````
  File "20191217_Access2PG.py", line 122, in <module>
    filter_mdb(args.bucket,args.profile)
  File "20191217_Access2PG.py", line 119, in filter_mdb
    s3_download(bucket, mdbList)
  File "20191217_Access2PG.py", line 103, in s3_download
    get_tables(path)
  File "20191217_Access2PG.py", line 84, in get_tables
    table_data(table_names)
  File "20191217_Access2PG.py", line 69, in table_data
    df_to_postgres(item, csv_file)
  File "20191217_Access2PG.py", line 48, in df_to_postgres
    df.to_sql(table_name.lower(), engine, if_exists='replace', method=psql_insert_copy)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2712, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 518, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1320, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize, method=method)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 734, in insert
    keys, data_list = self.insert_data()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 710, in insert_data
    d = np.array(b.get_values(), dtype=object)
MemoryError```
````

Comment: you'll need to chunksize argument inside `df.to_sql(....,chunksize=10000)`[docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: is there a reason you can not use `copy_to` from the `psycopg2` library which takes in a file object as opposed to holding the whole datatset in memory?

Comment: Is the table indexed, or does it have foreign keys, or does it have insert triggers?  That will greatly slow down the inserts.

Comment: "exceeding the CPU power of my EC2 instance" that just means it runs slower.  Is that the problem, or are you have some issue other than slowness?

Comment: @Datanovice I tried adding a chunksize argument and the script is still failing due to memory error. I'll add the error message to my original post.

Comment: @Amanser as a proof of concept, you might want to reduce the chunk size to something extremely small since you're still getting a memory error

Comment: @brddawg I should have mentioned that this script sucessfully inserted 51 other tables before this memory error on the table with 1.2 million rows.

Comment: @aws_apprentice Did you mean copy_from? I looked it up and am trying to get it to work now. The issue that I am running into is that psycopg2 wants me to create a table first. The functions that I am using above create the table.

Comment: so create the table first before uploading it? seems like a small price to pay in order to speed things up

Comment: @Amanser when you used chunksize was the size smaller then the largest successful table? seems like that should have worked especially given the previous tables. along those lines, are there more columns in this table then others?

Comment: @brddawg Yes, I set the chunksize to 50K and other tables that have 150K-300K rows were created sucessfully.